# UITableView scrolling and contentMode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to set a my UITableView to a smaller height and have set the contentMode as well, however, I can't get it to scroll.. it just cuts down the size. What am I doing wrong?

```
 [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 80)];
            [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 250)];
            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that you seem to be trying to set the contentSize of a `UITableView` directly (which you shouldn't do) you are setting a content size of height 80 and a frame of height 250. And `80 < 250` so there's no need to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

In nutshell, this will work

```
        [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 251)];
        [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 250)];
        [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```